# Cartopy: How to add a marker on a NearsidePerspective

Tags: matplotlib, maps, cartopy

I'm trying to add a marker at the center of a map, just a small red dot. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature


data = {
    'lat': 11.9320027,
    'lng': -86.055024,
    'time': '2022-01-01T00:33:32.401Z',
    'place': 'Catarina, Nicaragua',
}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), frameon=False)

projection = ccrs.NearsidePerspective(
    central_longitude=data['lng'],
    central_latitude=data['lat'],
    satellite_height=500000,
)
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=projection)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linewidth=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS, linewidth=0.3)
ax.add_image(cimgt.Stamen('watercolor'), 6)

# ax.plot([point['lng']], [point['lat']], marker='.', color='red', markersize=5, alpha=0.7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.show()
```

With the `marker` code commented out (like it currently is in the code) the image looks like this:

[image]

but if you uncomment the `marker` line - the result is not what I'd expect it  to be:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:**

as per @RutgerKassies - this is the way to go:

```
ax.plot(data['lng'], data['lat'], marker='.', color='red', markersize=5, alpha=0.7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_global()
```

---

Looks like plotting the red dot was messing the limits. This is the working code for plotting the red dot:

```
extent = ax.get_extent()
ax.plot(data['lng'], data['lat'], marker='.', color='red', markersize=5, alpha=0.7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.set_xlim(extent[:2])
ax.set_ylim(extent[2:])
```

Comment: You can call `ax.set_global()` to automatically use the limits of the chosen projection. Otherwise Matplotlib will consider the point to be the only artist in the axes, and use that to automatically guess the limits of the plot.